# Creating Checkbox list in Python script tool dialog ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, parameters

I'm creating a Toolbox (.atbx) in ArcGIS Pro, that uses a Python script I'm developing. Basically, the feature I want to add in that tool is making the user to select (using a checkbox) a set of maps he or she wants to create dynamically.

There're 47 different maps as options. Today, all this 47 is done alltogether. However, there's no need to run all at once, and it'll be great if I can make the users selected some they want.
NOTE: It'll be very helpfull to add a CLEAR ALL button and a SELECT ALL button for clearing or selecting all checkboxes at once.

Here is an example:

[image]

How can I achieve that in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Make a parameter with a Data Type = String and Multiple values
  enabled

[image]

- Set Filter to Value List and add your map names:

[image]

- When you run the tool, you can select individual maps from the dropdown, or click the Add many button and select multiple with the option to select/unselect all

[image: Select one]

[image: Select many]